# Extending scopes

Tags: ubuntu-touch, scopes

Is it possible to extend existing scopes on ubuntu-touch?
Take the news scope for example, would it be possible to add additional news sources besides the ones already present (bbc news, euronews, cnet, etc...)? If so, how can this be done, is there documentation available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a recent [message](https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/msg11876.html) on the ubuntu-phone team [mailing list](https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/maillist.html), it is not yet possible to extend the news scope.